# How to add meta tags in multiple languages

Tags: seo, keyword, meta-tags, multilingual, keyword-search

We have a multilanguage single page html site. What we do is, we take the browser's language on `document.ready` and translate page content in that language and also we have given facility to change the language so that the user can view the page in that language.

```
<h1 key="key_title"><h1>
```

This is a tag in our site. `translate()` function will set `html` or `text` of this tag languagewise. And so all the tags are translated.

The question is how can we manage meta kewords and description in multiple languages? The meta tags are by default in english. And are changed dynamically. We have solutions that suggests using Transcribe. Is there is any easy way.?

Comment: 1) Are you aware that this is not a good way to handle multi-lingual content? The best practice is to have separate pages/URLs per language.  2) Did you consider using the `lang` attribute?

Comment: We are going to add separate pages for different languages. What are the issues with the above method?

Comment: Ah, not sure if I understood your architecture correctly. In case you have the same URL for languages, search engines won’t be able to link the intended version in the search results.

Comment: @unor we have added sitemap. There are 3 links two with the language parameter so that we can get the language and call the translate Function

Comment: I see, sounds good :)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363908/

Comment: My Qustion Related Google bot ?

Comment: My Question is related to Google bot and also my site is not redirect to others page means Ex:- www.tickitbookit.com  when iam typing in Google its says that (Did u Mean: thinkitbookit.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you translate on `document.ready`, you could extend your javascript code to modify the meta keyword and description tags too.

See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47212820/520957