# Webpage meta description in multiple languages

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core

Is it possible to add `<meta name="description" content="..." />` for multiple languages?

**I know that question was already asked and answered on stack, but the answer does not solve my problem.**

The trick is that my website content is taken from resource files, which are in PL and EN versions. The application uses ASP.Net Core middleware (`UseRequestLocalization()`) to decide which resource file use, based on the browser settings or on the cookie value created when user changes the language manually, so there is a possibility that it will never be created.

As you can see, there are no direct indications of in which language the site currently is displayed, as I don't push that info into URL, nor store it in HTML tags.

I'd be perfectly happy with being able to do something like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="some polish content" />
<meta name="description" content="some english content" />
```

and having a browser to decide which one to use, based on browser language settings. Is something like this even possible in ASP.Net Core application?

**EDIT because people vote to close for duplicate question without reading mine...**

Yes, I have read [HTML: Multiple language meta descriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363908/html-multiple-language-meta-descriptions). It shed some light on the topic, but first of all it does not really helpful in my case, second of all, it was written way before ASP.Net Core 1.0 was even introduced, so I'm asking if maybe ASP.Net Core has a way to workaround this problem. There is a reason I tagged my question in a way I did... Please read something more than just a title before you vote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML: Multiple language meta descriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363908/html-multiple-language-meta-descriptions)

Comment: There was a discussion before you may reference this in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363908/html-multiple-language-meta-descriptions)

Comment: Have you even read my question? "I know that question was already asked and answered on stack, but the answer does not solve my problem."... Yes, I found the answer you are referring to as well and this is the one I said is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post multiple versions of a meta description. However, if your site advertises localized versions, you can ensure that the meta description itself is localized in the correct language. Put another way, you can't just have an English page with meta descriptions in English and Polish, but you can have an English version of the page with an English meta description and a Polish version of the page with a Polish meta description.

See the [documentation on localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for more info on how to set everything up. Once you have localization set up for your project and your resources established, it's a simple matter of injecting `IViewLocalizer` into your view:

```
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

...

<meta name="description" content="@Localizer["This is my meta description"]" />
```

Comment: Tried that already and it didn't work for me. All it did was displaying "This is my meta description" instead of resource the key was referring to (checked on browser's developers tools)

Comment: Assuming you set up localization correctly, then the culture was off. Otherwise, there's an issue with your localization setup.