# Angular head meta tags localize/translate

Tags: angular, meta-tags, translate, ngx-translate

**Technology used**: Angular

**What I want to achieve**: I want to translate meta tags in html.index for optimized SEO

**Current situation**: my site is translated using ngx-translate, and is on a single page. So I don't have a "https://my.site/fr/page" - "https://my.site/en/page" structure but only "https://my.site/page" and language is set by default thanks to

```
this.translateService.getBrowserLang()
```

Here is my index.html (simplified):

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <title >My title in french</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="description" content="my description in french">
    <meta name="keywords" content="my keywords in french">
</head>
</html>
```

**Problem**: I've found plenty of solutions for translating these meta tags (in javascript/typescript, with pipes, with a variable, by adding them to the code, redirecting to another translated page...).
But when a user searches in his browser and sees the title and description in the list of different sites (the result of his search), the javascript doesn't seem to be activated, which seems normal to me since the user isn't yet on the site.

**My question**: How can I translate these meta tags so that they're visible in the list of sites on a browser search?

Comment: have you tried this? <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en,hu">
Telling google the content can be in multiple languages? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363908/html-multiple-language-meta-descriptions

Comment: It does not really help, this balise indicate the languages so it is useful, but do not help to translate descriptions and keywords.
I don't think it is what i need.
Thanks anyway.